# Linked server and temp table issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I had our vendor create a linked server (SQL Server 2008) to our Server (SQL Server 2000).

This was in response to an issue I had with the vendor changing a data type to `varchar(max)`. I was informed that I should create a link from 2008 to 2000 to resolve the issue. Now that I have accomplished this task, when I run my query that links to a table on the SQL Server 2000 I receive this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Invalid object name
>   'dbo.tbl_QClients'.  The linked server
>   has permissions to this table.

This is basically what my query looks like;

```
Select
  Col1,
  Col2,
  Col3,
  ...
INTO
  #temptable
FROM
  tbl_on_SQL2000
...
```

It's little more complex than this (multiple joins) but this is basically the query.  The one thing I found is when I remove the `INTO #temptable` from the query it will not give me an error. Any ideas?

Thanks for you time.

Regards,
Oscar

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have write permissions, SELECT ... INTO creates a new table so that's most likely why it's giving you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the temp table before the insert...

```
CREATE #temptable (
   blah,
   blah,
   blah
)

INSERT INTO
   #temptable
SELECT
   blah
FROM
   blah
```

I've often experienced 'unexpected' behaviour when joining tables from one server on to tables from another server.  Mostly because SQL is good at pulling data from a remote server [it's often pulled as one large set], but poor and pushing data to a remote server [it's often done one record at a time].  Because of this I tend to reformulate by queries into smaller and simpler ones, getting the behaviour and performance I expect.